# About IOCTL system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The prototype of IOCTL system call in linux is

```
int ioctl(struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

All other file operations like read(),write(),llseek(),mmap() etc.. have only struct file * as argument. But, why IOCTL call needs struct inode * to be passed.
Is there any specific use of it?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl

Answer (score 0):

Which kernel version you are taking about, now ioctl doesn't has the inode pointer as its parameter. Previously there used to be, but I think from 2.6.36 kernel onwards it has been removed.

Comment: In LDD3 the prototype of IOCTL is given like this, i think LDD3 is referring to 2.6.10 kernel.

Comment: Most of the API has been changed after the book LDD3, so don't look for the function names and variable names in the LDD3, read that book only for concepts and go and read the kernel source of the version that you are working for actual usage of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `ioctl` is, at least according to the manpage, `int ioctl(int d, int request, ...);`. The `...` bit is important - variadic arguments, meaning the remaining arguments depend on the first ones, much like `printf`. Any use for a `struct inode *` would stem from the specific `ioctl` request you're making.